# How to I pass data from a top level route to inner routes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react application that has routes configured as such

`/packages/:packageId/years/:yearsId` where `/packages` returns a component that has a link to `/packages/:packageId` which continues rendering down to the final path of `/packages/:packageId/years/:yearsId`.

Now the issue is that I'd like to fetch data from an API starting from `/packages/:packageId` and pass it down to the component which renders from `/packages/:packageId`.

I'm wondering what the best strategy to do this would be. Currently, I'm passing state through a link component to link between the components as

```
import { faAngleRight } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

interface IProps {
    path: string;
    state?: object
}

/**
 * A right facing angle that acts as a <Link /> component in the cell of tables. 
 * @param {IProps}
 */
const ArrowLink = ({ path, state }: IProps) => {
    return (
        <Link 
            to={{
                pathname: path,
                state: state
            }}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faAngleRight}
                    size="lg"
                    aria-label="open menu icon"
                />
        </Link>
    );
};

export default ArrowLink;
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing things. Should I be using a `Context` and passing down information from the top level? I thought about going down this path, but I wasn't sure what to do if someone just went to `/packages/:packageId/years/:yearsId` immediately (as then the data would not have been loaded from the top level API call). Would I just have to make a function in the `Context` in order to have a function that fetches data if the `Context` is `null` or something?

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom` uses `context` internally so I suggest you use what it gives you and don't complicate your code unnecessarily. here is what I think you need to do based on your descriptions.

you need to check the state you're getting from `react router` in the `/packages/:packageId/years/:yearsId` component and see if it exists or not, if it doesn't exist just call your api (this is for the user who go directly to that component).

for those users who go from `/packages/:packageId` component to `/packages/:packageId/years/:yearsId` component you already made an api call and you just pass the result through `react router` state.

your `/packages/:packageId/years/:yearsId` component should look like this:

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
  if(location.state){
    //use the state 
  }else {
    //make an api call
  }
}, [])
```

if you showed actual code from those components I could be more specific

Comment: So I guess the question is does that "fetched data" really count as the state of the location? It seems like a hacky sorta way in order to actually data passed around. I was going to go about the way you described it, but looking at the examples it seemed like using `location.state` contained information about maybe where the user came from etc.

Comment: I used `location.state` as an example you need to check that if you're passing some data in you're location just check for the data you need like this `location.state && location.state.dataFromApi`

Comment: @efxgamer the way I showed you above is good for performance. you can also not check for the `state` you're passing through `react router` and just call your api every time the `/packages/:packageId/years/:yearsId` components will render

Comment: @efxgamer Did you implement the solution?

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me to put application state in `location.state` when it feels like it would be more for navigation state.